# Interprocess communication with Matlab on Windows

Tags: matlab, dll, ipc, shared-memory, named-pipes

I'm building a game in Unity3D that integrates with some code in Matlab. I'm looking for 1-way communication channel from Unity3D to Matlab on one computer.

The message is a short string.

The frequency of these messages is very low.

**Example:**

- I start my game in Unity3D.
- At the start, Unity3D send out `'message1'` to Matlab
- 30 seconds later Unity3D sends out `'message2'` to Matlab
- 30 seconds later Unity3D sends out `'message3'` to Matlab

**I know my programming knowledge is not advanced enough to do this by my own.** I've been doing a ton of research and need advice on what to focus my efforts on. I don't need any sort of authentication protocol because I'm just using one computer.

**Based on my description above what IPC do you think I should use and why?** I need a direction on where to focus my work on because I am not very advanced.

- DLL to share memory between two processes
- TCP sockets
- UDP sockets *(what's the difference with TCP socket in my case?)*
- (I can't use named pipes because Unity3D does not support it.)

Comment: As the frequency is so low, why don't you use files ?

Comment: how critical is the time of detection of a new message from matlab ? Does Matlab has to do something straight away or a few seconds after would be all right ?

Comment: I need the time detection to be straight away. Less than 1 second. I don't want the user to feel a delay. Can file write/read do that?

Comment: For one-way comms on Windows, there are like [a million ways](https://goo.gl/0bfEJk). Ah, ok, nine ways. Raw file access (not listed there because it's potentially flaky) is probably easiest to get to grips with. In Unity, write a temp file with your message, close it, then rename it to a known name. In Matlab, poll for the existence of the named file, can be doing other work meantime if need be. When the file appears, read it, action it, and delete it. YMMV, it's a bit dependent on caching on the FS. If you want a more elegant solution, I'd probably be looking at UDP (sockets) for this.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is MATLAB engine API. see : 
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-c-c-and-fortran-programs.html?refresh=true

And there is a very nice detailed demo posted here :
http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~jsp/Downloads/MatlabEngine/MatlabEngine.pdf
I've tested it and it worked !